# how to upload subfolder form google drive to colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i write python project in colab
i need to add more than python file in the notbook
i cant upload from subfolder in the drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/MyDrive/')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if I've understood your question well, but I trust you're trying to work around some files from your Google Drive directories in your Colab nootbook.

For that matter, first you need to mount your drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Running `!pwd` is going to print your current working directory. By default, you should get:

```
!pwd
... /content
```

You could also check out what's inside the directories using `!ls`. For example:

```
!ls
... gdrive  sample_data
!ls /content/gdrive/MyDrive
... dir1    dir2    # content of your Google Drive
!ls /content/gdrive/MyDrive/dir1
... the_file.csv    # a file located in dir1 in your Google Drive
```

Let's say you have a CSV file named *the_file.csv* located in *dir1* and you are going to read it using `pandas`. There are three solutions for this:

**Solution №1: (changing your working directory)**

In this method, you change the default working directory to your desired one:

```
from google.colab import drive # to mount your Google Drive
from os import chdir # to alter your working directory
import pandas as pd # to read the CSV file in our example

drive.mount('/content/gdrive') # mounting Google Drive
chdir('/content/gdrive/My Drive/dir1') # setting the working directory to "dir1" in your drive
df = pd.read_csv('the_file.csv') # reading the file from dir1
```

Note that you could confirm if `chdir()` actually worked by running `!pwd`.

**✓ Solution №2: (absolute addressing)** | ***Recommended***

In this method, your working directory stays as it was and you use absolute paths.

```
from google.colab import drive # to mount your Google Drive
import pandas as pd # to read the CSV file in our example

drive.mount('/content/gdrive') # mounting Google Drive
path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/dir1/' # absolute path
df = pd.read_csv(path + 'the_file.csv') # reading the file from dir1
```

**Solution №3: (relative addressing)**

In this method, your working directory stays as it was and you use relative paths which are shorter. Be advised though, that in this method, changing the working directory before a code block containing relative paths might cause malfunctions.

```
from google.colab import drive # to mount your Google Drive
import pandas as pd # to read the CSV file in our example

drive.mount('/content/gdrive') # mounting Google Drive
path = './gdrive/MyDrive/dir1/' # relative path
df = pd.read_csv(path + 'the_file.csv') # reading the file from dir1
```

---

Some useful links:

- [Absolute Path vs Relative Path in Linux/Unix](https://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/)
- [Python os.chdir method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/)
- [External data in Colab: Local Files, Drive, Sheets, and Cloud Storage](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb)

Comment: thanks for your answer it was very useful